# Getting the height of a tree with a recursive function

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, tree

I want to solve the cousera assignment on getting a tree's height. It asks me to get the height with a recursive function. I wrote this function but I still get none. The input in first line is the number of nodes, the second line is a list of numbers that each points to the index of the parent of that node (-1 value means that that node is the root).

I tried to print the `max_height` and it gives me a list of numbers. When I debugged it I saw that it first works as excepted but in the middle when the flow goes back the values get changed.

```
def compute_height(n, parents, postion=0, hight=0, max_hight=0, current=0):

    if postion == n-1:
        print(max_hight)
        return max_hight

    if current != -1:
        compute_height(n, parents, postion, hight+1,
                       max(max_hight, hight), parents[current])

    compute_height(n, parents, postion+1, 0, max_hight, postion+1)
```

It returns `None`. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: What is the input and expected output?

Comment: first line : 5 , second line : 4 -1 4 1 1 output(should be) : 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you got stuck with your recursive function and did not know how to move forward. I have changed it quite considerably to achieve this task in an efficient manner.

In general, to solve problems like these, the most important thing in terms of efficiency is to have a way of **keeping track** of where you have been already so that you do **not** repeat unnecessary work. You also want to make sure that you visit every leaf of the tree, as you do not know which one will be the deepest.

There is also a use of two functions here that are obviously very related. The first is the *driver*(1) function and is usually helpful when you have a *recursive*(2) function and want to call it with a specific set of arguments to start it off. Or when you want to run it in a for loop like I do here.

Let me know if there is something that does not make sense:

```py
# Computes the height of the tree
def compute_height(n, parents):
    # We make a list to keep track of which nodes have already been visited
    heights = [-1 for x in range(n)]

    # Make sure you visit every node if it is not already visited
    for i, val in enumerate(heights):
        if (val == -1):
            recurse_compute_height(n, parents, i, heights)

    return(max(heights))

# Recursively computes the height for the current node 
def recurse_compute_height(n, parents, index, heights):
    parent = parents[index]

    # Base case for when you reach the root
    if parent == -1:
        return 1

    # Leverage the parent's height, if already computed
    if (heights[parent] != -1):
        heights[index] = heights[parent] + 1
    # Or compute the node's and its parents's height
    else:
        heights[index] = recurse_compute_height(n, parents, parent, heights) + 1

    return heights[index]

# Input and run 
n = 5 
parents = [4, -1, 4, 1, 1, 0]
res = compute_height(n, parents)
print(res)
```

Output

```
3
```

Comment: thank you very much you really  helped me ,i get it but how can i solve these problems by my own ,what would i do or what should i read ,thank you again :)

Comment: @MahmoudZeyada that is why I added the descriptions before the code, so you can understand my thought process and see why I did what I did. I would recommend to you to keep trying to solve problems like these. This seems like it was a bit high-level for you so maybe start with easier problems and move on to harder ones as you feel more confident and learn more. A good site to do this is hackerrank.com. Also watch videos about things that confuse you!

Comment: btw i modified my solution but it takes too long time to evaluate the result , your solution is great but it causes Segmentation fault when n = 100000 takeing into consideration that i run the script in  other  thread which have max_stack = 3**27

Comment: @MahmoudZeyada did you find a way to solve it without any issues in the end then?

Comment: yes i used for loop without any recursive calls and it worked but it exceeds the time limit which is 10 sec note i wrote the whole test cases and tests it on my local machine